# I used Gams, it gives an error in the code

Tags: gams-math

I coded that model using gams, but when I pressed run, it an gives error on line 42.(line starting with cons2(i)) Before that it was giving an error in the last two lines. The last two lines are "solve vaccination using lp minimizing z;" the following code was "solve vaccination using lp minimizing objfunction;" so I deleted objfunction and replaced it with z. and the code now "solve vaccination using lp minimizing z;" but now it gives another error, why is it giving?

After updating my codes, it does not give an error, but when I enter data to try, no feasible result can be found.

Below is the updated version of my codes.

```
sets
i index of districts in labc /d1,
 d2/
j index of possible location sites for vaccination center / 1
 2
 3
 4/;

variables

x(i,j)

y(j)

z ;

binary variables
x(i,j)

r(i,j);

parameters
S maximum service distances
/ 1 20
  2 19
  3 45
  4 40 /
c(j) cost
/ 1 20000
  2 30000
  3 45000
  4 25000 /
a (i) population
/ d1 250000
  d2 350000 /
K(j) capacity
/ 1 20000
  2 30000
  3 45000
  4 55000/;
table d(i,j) shortest travel  distance between points
    1  2  3  4
d1  8  10 12 6
d2  12 18 10 10;


equations

objfunction
cons1
cons2
cons3;

objfunction.. z =e= sum(j, c(j)*y(j));

cons1(i).. sum((j),(r(i,j)*x(i,j))) =g= 1;
cons2(i,j).. x(i,j) =g= y(j);
cons3(j).. sum((i),(r(i,j)*a(i)*x(i,j))) =l= K(j)*y(j);


Model new1 / all /;
solve new1 using RMINLP minimizing z;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message (did you note that in the log or lst file?) says:

```
Unknown symbol
```

pointing to `Mx` in equation `cons2`. The problem is, that `Mx` was never declared. You need to declare it probably as `Variable`. Or did you maybe mean `x` instead of `Mx`?

I assumed that you meant `x` and tried that. After changing that, you'll get an error since `j` is not controlled in `cons2`. Now it depends on what this equation is supposded to do. Do you want to sum over `j` or declare the equation for each `j`?

---

Reply for the EDITED question:

There are many reasons for an infeasible model: Problematic data, flaw in the model formulation, ... Getting help for this is not always easy and it usually helps to actually describe the idea of the single equations and to try to narrow the problem down to a particular equation (or set of equations). Especially without any comments or explanatory text for the equations, it is not so easy for an external to understand the ideas of your model and help to find a problem.

One approach for you to tackle such a problem is to use a solver in GAMS, that has an IIS (irreducible infeasible set) capability, which might help to find the root problem.

Anyway, in your model you seem to have insufficient `capacity` (150,000 in total) for your `population` (600,000 in total). If I add more capacity, I get a feasible solution (I have not looked at that in detail).

Comment: I fixed that part. At the moment, it does not give an error, but when I enter data to try, no feasible result can be found.

Comment: I've updated my question with my edited code.

Comment: I updated my reply (see lower part of the answer).